# Most efficient way to produce a Python dictionary given a list

Tags: python, performance, optimization, data-structures

I'm looking for optimizations on the following problem (I've got some working code but I'm fairly sure it could be quicker and is written in a bad way). I've got a list of SKUs (between 6 and 9 digit numbers) that I'm looking up information on on Amazon. The working code is given below:

```
def buildDictionary2(stringy):
    x = stringy.xpath('//sellersku/text()|//product/descendant::amount[1]/text()')
    Sku_To_Price = {}
    for items in range(len(x)):
        if x[items] in myList:
            try:
                if x[items+1] not in myList:
                    Sku_To_Price[x[items]] = x[items+1]
                else:
                    Sku_To_Price[x[items]] = ''
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    return Sku_To_Price
```

where x is a dictionary of generally alternating SKUs and prices. However, the complication arises whereby the price can't be found. In this case the list (x) goes SKU, SKU instead of SKU price.

At the moment I'm looking up in the list of SKUs (in the global variable myList) but can't help this is of time complexity O(e^n). Given I'm looking at working with something in the region of 20,000 SKUs I'd rather this wasn't the case.

Is there a way to make this less complex - the desired output is a dictionary with each SKU once (as a key) and it's corresponding price as the value (with no entry if if there is no price).

edit:

a sample of the XML being parsed

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult SellerSKU="X" status="Success">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" 
             xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>X</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
        <SKUIdentifier>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <SellerId>X</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>10065897</SellerSKU>
        </SKUIdentifier>
      </Identifiers>
      <LowestOfferListings>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>3</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>23.68</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>X</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
      </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
  </GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult>
  <GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult SellerSKU="X" status="X">
    <AllOfferListingsConsidered>X</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
    <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
             xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>X</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
        <SKUIdentifier>
          <MarketplaceId>X</MarketplaceId>
          <SellerId>X</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>9854521</SellerSKU>
        </SKUIdentifier>
      </Identifiers>
      <LowestOfferListings>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>2.68</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>8</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>4</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
        <LowestOfferListing>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>X</ItemCondition>
            <ItemSubcondition>X</ItemSubcondition>
            <FulfillmentChannel>X</FulfillmentChannel>
            <ShipsDomestically>X</ShipsDomestically>
            <ShippingTime>
              <Max>X</Max>
            </ShippingTime>
            <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>X</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
          </Qualifiers>
          <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
          <SellerFeedbackCount>X</SellerFeedbackCount>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>X</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>X</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </Price>
          <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>X</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
        </LowestOfferListing>
      </LowestOfferListings>
    </Product>
  </GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>X</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResponse>
```

and myList looks like:

```
myList = ['10032590',
'10043503',
'10047539',
'10055404',
'10058424'...
]
```

Using the first answer below I'm getting the following error message:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

where I believe the relevant code is:

```
def xml_to_dict(self, xml):
    doc = lh.fromstring(xml)
    d = {}
    for product in doc.xpath('.//product'):
        sku = product.xpath('.//sellersku/text()')
        amount = product.xpath('./descendant::amount[1]/text()')
        d[sku] = amount
    return d
```

Comment: Can you include a short sample of SKUs and prices?

Comment: Also, a sample of the XML you are parsing would be helpful, I suspect that there are better ways to extract SKUs and prices that could help make this simpler.

Comment: `range(len(x))` is decidedly anti-idiomatic for python.  If you absolutely must have numeric indices and items, use `for idx, item in enumerate(alist)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Have added XML and myList as per request :)

Comment: @Kali_89 -- I had a missing `[0]` (second line in my answer) but corrected, please try again with the new code...with an added check...

Comment: Favorited and +1, this is very interesting :) May I ask what brought this on?

Comment: @RandyE

Hi Randy,

This question is, I guess, the first steps in getting to grip with the Amazon marketplace API (Amazon MWS). One of the tools on there allows you to run a pricing comparison report of SKUs you have listed and compare that to the current lowest price. When you've got one or two SKUs, obviously it's fine to check them manually. As you increase the number of SKUs and the regularity with which you want to check them, efficiency becomes much more important - hence the question!

Comment: @Kali_89 Ah ok, yeah I can see where this would be much more efficient than checking everything manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d={}
for product in doc.xpath('.//product'):
    sku = product.xpath('.//sellersku/text()')[0]
    price = product.xpath('./descendant::amount[1]/text()')
    if price: # if theres a possibility of sku missing replace with:
              # "if price and sku"
              #
              # if you have duplicate sku's and you don't want them overwritten 
              # add "and sku not in d" check
        d[sku]= price[0]
```

Comment: Just to say, haven't forgotten this/stopped working on it. It's just running now. Will update once it's completed.

Comment: @Kali_89 -- let's keep our fingers crossed :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked, takes about 1 hour to do the 22,000 SKUs which I'm counting as fairly good :)